# CMake a few questions about writing my own find_package module

Tags: cmake

I am a novice in the filed of CMake and I learn how to write my own `find_package()` module by following the example in the book ***CMake Cookbook***. The following CMakeLists.txt file is provided with the official example.

```
if(NOT ZeroMQ_ROOT)
  set(ZeroMQ_ROOT "$ENV{ZeroMQ_ROOT}")
endif()

if(NOT ZeroMQ_ROOT)
  find_path(_ZeroMQ_ROOT NAMES include/zmq.h)
else()
  set(_ZeroMQ_ROOT "${ZeroMQ_ROOT}")
endif()

find_path(ZeroMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS NAMES zmq.h HINTS ${_ZeroMQ_ROOT}/include)

if(ZeroMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  set(_ZeroMQ_H ${ZeroMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS}/zmq.h)

  function(_zmqver_EXTRACT _ZeroMQ_VER_COMPONENT _ZeroMQ_VER_OUTPUT)
    set(CMAKE_MATCH_1 "0")
    set(_ZeroMQ_expr "^[ \\t]*#define[ \\t]+${_ZeroMQ_VER_COMPONENT}[ \\t]+([0-9]+)$")
    file(STRINGS "${_ZeroMQ_H}" _ZeroMQ_ver REGEX "${_ZeroMQ_expr}")
    string(REGEX MATCH "${_ZeroMQ_expr}" ZeroMQ_ver "${_ZeroMQ_ver}")
    set(${_ZeroMQ_VER_OUTPUT} "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  endfunction()

  _zmqver_EXTRACT("ZMQ_VERSION_MAJOR" ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR)
  _zmqver_EXTRACT("ZMQ_VERSION_MINOR" ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR)
  _zmqver_EXTRACT("ZMQ_VERSION_PATCH" ZeroMQ_VERSION_PATCH)

  # We should provide version to find_package_handle_standard_args in the same format as it was requested,
  # otherwise it can't check whether version matches exactly.
  if(ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT GREATER 2)
    set(ZeroMQ_VERSION "${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR}.${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR}.${ZeroMQ_VERSION_PATCH}")
  else()
    # User has requested ZeroMQ version without patch part => user is not interested in specific patch =>
    # any patch should be an exact match.
    set(ZeroMQ_VERSION "${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR}.${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR}")
  endif()

  if(NOT ${CMAKE_C_PLATFORM_ID} STREQUAL "Windows")
    find_library(ZeroMQ_LIBRARIES 
        NAMES 
          zmq 
        HINTS 
          ${_ZeroMQ_ROOT}/lib
          ${_ZeroMQ_ROOT}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        )
  else()
    find_library(ZeroMQ_LIBRARIES
        NAMES
          libzmq
          "libzmq-mt-${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_PATCH}"
          "libzmq-${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET}-mt-${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_PATCH}"
          libzmq_d
          "libzmq-mt-gd-${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_PATCH}"
          "libzmq-${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET}-mt-gd-${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MAJOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_MINOR}_${ZeroMQ_VERSION_PATCH}"
        HINTS
          ${_ZeroMQ_ROOT}/lib
        )
  endif()
endif()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

find_package_handle_standard_args(ZeroMQ
  FOUND_VAR
    ZeroMQ_FOUND
  REQUIRED_VARS
    ZeroMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ZeroMQ_LIBRARIES
  VERSION_VAR
    ZeroMQ_VERSION
  )
```

I have two questions toward the above example. The first one is that in the function scope `_zmqver_EXTRACT` we first set the `CMAKE_MATCH_1` to 0 and then we do this command `set(${_ZeroMQ_VER_OUTPUT} "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}" PARENT_SCOPE)`. However, it seems that the value of `CMAKE_MATCH_1` is always 0. In my opinion, the version information should be stored in the variable `ZeroMQ_ver`.

What's more, I do not know what the usage of the variable `ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT`. It seems that this variable is undefined.

Comment: "it seems that the value of `CMAKE_MATCH_1` is always 0." - This variable is set in `string(REGEX MATCH)` call on successfull match, see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/string.html#regex-match). "I do not know what the usage of the variable `ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT`" - This variable denotes number of version components, passed to `find_package()` call. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have checked the documentation and I think the ‘string(REGEX MATCH)’ call successfully and store the result in the variable ‘_ZeroMQ_ver”. In terms of the variable ‘ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT’, I do not know where it’s value is defined or set.

Comment: From description of regular expressions: `() ... Additionally it is saved by all regular expression-related commands, including e.g. if(MATCHES), in the variables CMAKE_MATCH_<n> for <n> 0..9.` So `CMAKE_MATCH_1` contains matching for the first expression in `(...)`. BTW, instead of guessing "it seems that the value of `CMAKE_MATCH_1` is always 0" or "It seems that this variable is undefined." (about `ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT` variable), you may just add into the script appropriate `message()` call which would print a value of the variable.

Comment: Concerning `ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT` variable. Actually, the script you show is NOT a `CMakeLists.txt` but `FindZeroMQ.cmake`. This script is intended to be called `find_package(ZeroMQ)`. And documentation of [find_package command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html) has these lines near the end: "`<package>_FIND_VERSION_COUNT` - number of version components, 0 to 4". In your case `<package>` is substituted with `ZeroMQ`. So, `ZeroMQ_FIND_VERSION_COUNT` variable is passed to your script and contains number of version components provided for `find_package` call.